# Keyboard layout handling in XAML Direct X Universal app

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp

I want to add text input in universal app (Direct X + XAML) such as chat box. Currently, I am using

```c
Window::Current->CoreWindow->KeyUp += ref new TypedEventHandler<CoreWindow^, KeyEventArgs^>(this, &MainPage::OnKeyUp);
Window::Current->CoreWindow->KeyDown += ref new TypedEventHandler<CoreWindow^, KeyEventArgs^>(this, &MainPage::OnKeyDown);
```

to capture individual key presses and process them to form text to display. The problem is that I do not know how to take keyboard layouts (e.g. French, German) into account. The class [Windows::UI::Core::KeyEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.keyeventargs.aspx) does not provide much information. Should there be a simple solution for this fundamental problem? How can I take raw keyboard input and convert them to Unicode characters based on the keyboard layout? (I believe that there should be a solution on Win32. It is so unfortunate that Microsoft's Direct X samples only considers touchscreen-only non-physical-keyboard scenario; contrary to their advertised Continuum/Universal approach in Windows 10.)

Note: I do not want to have a hack-ish solution like showing/hiding a XAML `EditBox` on top of Direct X `SwapChainPanel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translated characters are provided in the CoreWindows::[CharacterReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.core.corewindow.characterreceived.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event.

The Key events report only the keys, not the characters, and don't have enough data to translate to characters, especially for complex characters and non-keyboard input.